# Facebook customization, iframe/app vs fbml

Tags: facebook

I'm experimenting with facebook customization and was wondering what other peoples experience of the iframe/app route is.

Having constructed a page and an app (using a template) containing the content I find that the default page view is the wall and there seems to be no way to default to the app content. The iframe/app route also has a separate like button to the page.

Is there anyway around this or is this the normal customized facebook user experience, or have I taken the wrong approach? Does FBML offer a richer experience.

[facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Rad/117859608302744)

[app](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Rad/117859608302744?sk=app_195153080532098)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default page for non-fans to be the app content in the page settings. For people that are already fans, they will get the wall tab.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, do you know if it's possible to align the app like button with the page, so they act in concert?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it isn't. Maybe  you could try static FBML ?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be the route, looking at some of the major brand sites, like Facebook.com/nike they seem to have the same experience that I do. I looked at fbml tabs but they seem to have been depreciated.